# Conditional calculating the numbers of values in column with R

Tags: r, aggregate, apply

I have three vectors:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,3,3,  3,3,3,4,4,  5,5,5,5,5 )
y <- c(2,2,1,3,2, 1,4,2,2,NA, 3,3,3,4,NA, 1,4,4,2,NA)
w <- c(1,45,NA,45,NA,45,41,45,96,25,12,NA,7,NA,4,45,12,45,32,56)
```

How can I find the number of values in W (don`t count NA) for each X and for Y=1? For example, for x=1, number is 0; for x=2 the number is 1; for x=3 the number is 0; for x=4 the number is 0; for x=5 the number is 1

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
df<-data.frame(x,y,w)
nrow(df[which(x==1 & y==1 & !is.na(w)),])
```

or

```
df<-data.frame(x,y,w)
aggregate(w ~ x, data=df[which(df$y==1 & !is.na(df$w)),], FUN=length)
```

The second gives you a table

```
  x w
1 2 1
2 5 1
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is the accepted answer. It does not do what the OP asked. Either solution.

Comment: It does what the OP asked... The first returns the number for a particular x value. The second returns a table. The table does not have x =1,3,4 because those values are 0.

Comment: The second formula is better for me. You have two rows in result but how to make NA for other rows?

Comment: No it doesn't. Mine does. Yours does not. I do not see the zero values for x in your second solution and your first is even worse. It just returns `0`. The OP specifically asks for the zero results!

Comment: @user3742663 Do you really want NA for other rows? Or 0?

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon I was not sure if the OP wants to query the number by some particular x value. So I showed an example of x=1. I am aware of the fact that the first solution returns one value, not a table. Plus OP added "aggregate" as a tag. I thought he or she wants to use the aggregate function.

Comment: Yes, I want NA for other rows )

Comment: Using aggregate() function will make things more complicated than necessary if you want a final table to show NA. What you can do is to take @SimonO'Hanlon's table() expression, convert it to a data frame and then replace 0 with NA.

Comment: @Baboe Thank you. But how to solve the same problem  not only for y=1 but also for all values from y (1,2,3,4)? So the output should contain 20 rows including NAs.

Answer (score 3):

```
table( !is.na(w) & y==1 , x )
#       x
#        1 2 3 4 5
#  FALSE 5 2 4 1 3
#  TRUE  0 1 0 0 1
```

Or

```
table( !is.na(w) & y==1 , x )["TRUE",]
#1 2 3 4 5 
#0 1 0 0 1
```

To get this for all `y` values as well you can still use `table()`. The following tables the number of all non-`NA` value for each `x` and `y`...

```
table( x , y , ! is.na(w) )[,,"TRUE"]
#   y
#x   1 2 3 4
#  1 0 2 1 0
#  2 1 1 0 1
#  3 0 1 2 0
#  4 0 0 0 0
#  5 1 1 0 2
```

Comment: Thanks. But how to solve the same problem  not only for y=1 but also for all values from y in descending order (4,3,2,1)? So the output should contain 20 rows including NAs.

Comment: @user3742663 that's a bit of a different question, but see the edit!